# Display datetime at format ("YYYY-MM-DD") in v-calendar (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, frontend, vcalendar

```
          <DatePicker
            v-model="date"
            is-expanded
            is24hr
            :attributes="attrs"
            :model-config="{
              type: 'string',
              mask: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
            }"
            mode="date"
          >
          </DatePicker>
```

I tried to add "model-config" like this to  , but it still displayed in screen with "MM-DD-YYYY" format, the data in `date` is in correct format ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").

Dislpay in screen : "12-20-2021" (INCORRECT) => What I want: "2021-12-20"
data in `date` variable: "2021-12-20 14:20" (CORRECT)

That's is very weird. So how can I change the DISLPAY format of this datetime.
Thank you guy so much.
I'm using `v-calendar` version 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            <DatePicker
                v-model="date"
                is-expanded
                is24hr
                :attributes="attrs"
                :model-config="{
                  type: 'string',
                  mask: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
                }"
                :masks="{ L: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
                mode="date"
              >
              </DatePicker>
```

I fixed this problem by adding `masks` like below:
`:masks="{ L: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"` as a attribute and it works perfectly.